# Installing a video driver on the demo system

Tags: drivers, gpu-driver, testdrive

I want to test the latest Kubuntu distribution DVD on a new computer, but with this twist: I also want to install a video driver from a hardware website to see how well it works.  If I simply try to install the driver in the running demo and do nothing else, I don't think it gets activated. Normally that would happen after a restart.  But I can't do a restart in this case because that would reboot the DVD and I'd be back where I started.  How can I install the driver and get the demo system to use it?

Comment: You might be able to run `sudo restart lightdm` to do that.